# MYSQL: Find Start and End Timestamp of a consecutive count

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to output the start and end time of a series of positive numbers

For example; I have the following Table that has two columns Timestamp and Marker.Marker consists of a series of 1's and 0's:

I wish to count each series/ run of 1's and produce the timestamp when the series starts and ends

```
Time_stamp                 Marker

2012-01-01 00:01:00         1

2012-01-01 00:02:10         1

2012-01-01 00:03:01         1

2012-01-01 00:04:15         0

2012-01-01 00:05:12         0

2012-01-01 00:06:00         1

2012-01-01 00:07:02         1

2012-01-01 00:08:19         1

2012-01-01 00:09:11         1

2012-01-01 00:10:10         1
```

An example output table would show the count for each section of 1's for each run of the value and the time where the value starts and ends before a 0 appears.

```
Output Table:

Total Count       Start Timestamp            End Timestamp

   3              2012-01-01 00:01:00       2012-01-01 00:03:01 


   5              2012-01-01 00:06:00      2012-01-01 00:10:10
```

I've started some code (created a table named tbl) which gives the overall count of the number of 1's and start and End for the overall values. Not exactly what i need.

```
Select Consec,
SUM(IF(Consec = '1',1,0)) AS Total_Count,
Min(Time_stamp) AS Min_Timestamp,
Max(Time_stamp) AS Max_Timestamp
FROM(
SELECT 
  a.*, 
 @val:=0,
 @Zero:=0,
 IF (a.Marker=1,@val:=@val+1,@Zero) AS Consec
FROM tbl a
) a
```

I'm short on ideas. Any thoughts by anyone on how to adjust so I can identify individual runs of the value '1' and output the start and end timestamp for each run.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to give a unique index of each run / series and then use GROUP BY to get starting and ending timestamps.

Here you go:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), MIN(time_stamp) AS starttime, MAX(time_stamp) AS endtime
FROM (
  SELECT IF(@prev <> marker, @s:=@s+1, @s:=@s) AS `index`, 
    time_stamp, @prev:=marker marker
  FROM
    tbl, (SELECT @s:= 0, @prev:= -1) s
) tmp
WHERE marker = 1
GROUP BY `index`
```

Working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5f19c/3

Comment: Makes complete sense.I have applied this in the context of the issue I had.Works exactly as needed.

Answer (score 0):

For problems like this cursors are a efficient way to solve a problem that is inherently procedural rather than relational.

This code creates a cursor that iterates through your selected table and writes down every time it finds a change.

The advantage to this is there is no subquery needed, hence can handles tables as large as needed.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE markchange()
BEGIN    
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE a,start_time DATETIME;
DECLARE b,marker,count INT;
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT Time_stamp,Marker FROM targetTable
                       ORDER BY Time_stamp ASC;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;     
OPEN cur;       
FETCH cur INTO a,b;
SET start_time = a;
SET end_time = a;
SET marker = b;
SET count = 0;
read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO a,b;   
    IF done THEN
        INSERT INTO `Output Table` (count_col,start_time_col, end_time_col)
        VALUES (count,start_time, end_time);
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    SET count = count + 1;
    SET end_time = a;
    IF marker <> b THEN
        INSERT INTO `Output Table` (count_col,start_time_col, end_time_col)
        VALUES (count,start_time, end_time);
        SET start_time = a;
        SET marker = b;
        SET count = 0;
    END IF;
END LOOP;           
CLOSE cur;      
END
```