# MySQL: Get start & end timestamp for each day

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Similar to the question at [MYSQL: Find Start and End Timestamp of a consecutive count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407016/mysql-find-start-and-end-timestamp-of-a-consecutive-count), I have a table with similar data:

```
StatusTime          | Reading   
2014-01-01 00:00    | 255
2014-01-01 01:00    | 255
2014-01-01 02:00    | 255
2014-01-01 03:00    | 255
2014-01-01 04:00    | 255
2014-01-01 05:00    | 241
2014-01-01 06:00    | 189
2014-01-01 07:00    | 100
2014-01-01 08:00    | 20
2014-01-01 09:00    | 0
2014-01-01 10:00    | 1
2014-01-01 11:00    | 1
2014-01-01 12:00    | 0
2014-01-01 13:00    | 21
2014-01-01 14:00    | 1
2014-01-01 15:00    | 0
2014-01-01 16:00    | 12
2014-01-01 17:00    | 63
2014-01-01 18:00    | 102
2014-01-01 19:00    | 198
2014-01-01 20:00    | 255
2014-01-01 21:00    | 255
2014-01-01 22:00    | 255
2014-01-01 23:00    | 255
2014-01-02 00:00    | 255
2014-01-02 01:00    | 255
2014-01-02 02:00    | 255
2014-01-02 03:00    | 255
2014-01-02 04:00    | 255
2014-01-02 05:00    | 208
2014-01-02 06:00    | 100
2014-01-02 07:00    | 48
2014-01-02 08:00    | 0
2014-01-02 09:00    | 0
```

I'd like to extract the **start** and **end** timestamps where readings go **above 50** and **below 50**, respectively. I just can't get my head around the SQL presented in the other answer!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What would be your desired result? Just the times where it "flips"?

Comment: Yup - I'm trying to get the two times each day when the device reading  transitions above/below 50.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it only goes below/above again once per day, you can make the query quite simple; just find the min and max time where it's below, grouping by date.

```
SELECT
  DATE(statustime) statusdate,
  MIN(CASE WHEN reading<50 THEN statustime ELSE NULL END) start_time,
  MAX(CASE WHEN reading<50 THEN statustime ELSE NULL END) end_time
FROM myTable
GROUP BY statusdate
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62366/1).

Comment: Darn it! Spoke too soon - whilst I now get only two readings per day, they're the readings either side of midnight, not at the transition points :(

Comment: @user3061406 Um, could you add some sample data to the sqlfiddle? I'm guessing you have data which is not always higher at night and lower in the daytime in which case this query will break.

Comment: Finally got a dataset to load and it all works OK in SQL Fiddle, but it doesn't work on my rig here - Debian Linux, MySQL 5.5.34 - weird!

Comment: Scrub that - works fine, I had multiple sensor readings, so just had to add a HAVING clause. Many thanks for your help @Joachim

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(StatusTime), MIN(StatusTime) 
FROM table_name
WHERE Reading < 50 OR Reading > 50;
```

Comment: i think the problem with this answer is that the OP wants the start and end date

Comment: ? This will always output no results

Comment: change AND to OR and add MAX and MIN to your date select

Comment: woops, sorry fixed I think, my mysql skills are rusty

Comment: Thanks for this suggestions, however this gives me the min/max for the whole dataset. I'm looking for the times where the reading transitions above/below 50 (I'm expecting that to happen twice a day).

Comment: @user3061406 Does this work after adding in `DISTINCT`?

Comment: Unfortunately not - I get the same result: One start timestamp & one end timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

```
  select *
    (select max(StatusTime) from tbl where Reading > 50) above_50,
    (select min(StatusTime) from tbl where Reading < 50) bellow_50;
```

Comment: I had great hope for this, but I get a MySQL error: 1064 at line 2