# Differences between SQL Fiddle and local

Tags: mysql

Over here: [MySQL: Get start & end timestamp for each day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409068/mysql-get-start-end-timestamp-for-each-day/22409599?noredirect=1#comment34074185_22409599) I was given a working answer, but it only works for me in SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62366/1). When I run the same SQL on my Debian Linux / MySQL 5.5.34 I get incorrect results (start & end times are the closest reading to midnight)! Anyone got any suggestions as to what might be causing the problem?

Comment: give the full schema and we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake - real schema had another column for deviceID, and the data held readings for multiple devices. Once I added the following, all worked OK:

```
...
FROM myTable
HAVING deviceID = 1234
GROUP BY deviceID, StatusTime
```